# How can i remove the part "http://" from a string?

Tags: c#

I have this method:

```
private List<string> offline(string targetDirectory)
{
    if (targetDirectory.Contains("http://"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("true");
    }
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);
    List<string> directories = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(targetDirectory,"*.*",SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        for (int i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
        {
            string t = "http://" + dirs[i];
            directories.Add(t);
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hgjghj");
    }


    return directories;

}
```

This is the part:

```
if (targetDirectory.Contains("http://"))
{
     MessageBox.Show("true");
}
```

I'm getting a directory which give me all the directories in this directory and I'm adding to each directory the string `"http://"`.

The problem is when next time a directory is getting to the function its coming with `"http://"`

For example: `http://c:\\` or `http://c:\\windows`

And then the line

```
 DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory); // throws exception.
```

So I want that each time a directory is getting to the function to check if it starts with `"http://"` in the beginning, strip the `"http://"` part, get all the directories, and then add to each directory `"http://"` like now.

How can I remove `"http://"`?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I would be stricter than using `Contains` - I'd use `StartsWith`, and then `Substring`:

```
if (targetDirectory.StartsWith("http://"))
{
    targetDirectory = targetDirectory.Substring("http://".Length);
}
```

Or wrap it in a helper method:

```
public static string StripPrefix(string text, string prefix)
{
    return text.StartsWith(prefix) ? text.Substring(prefix.Length) : text;
}
```

It's not clear to me why you're putting the `http://` as a prefix anyway though, to be honest. I can't see how you'd expect a directory name prefixed with `http://` to be a valid URL. Perhaps if you could explain why you're doing it, we could suggest a better approach.

(Also, I really hope you don't have a try/catch block like that in your real code, and that normally you follow .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: Jon Skeet the reason that im using http:// in the beginning is to simulate offline websites. Im using this List of simulated web links in other functions thats why i wanted to add http:// in the beginning. I mean offline like when there is no internet connection. The reason is that im doing a webcrawler using a recrusive function and i wanted to be able to test and use my program event when there is no internet connection. So i thought when im in an off line mode to use the directories on hte hard disk like they were links. Ofcourse im not usinf Document and html and htmlagilitypack.

Comment: @user1741587: But they're *not* HTTP URLs. Why create a "link" that could never possibly work? Why not use `file://` for example? What you're doing now is simply confusing. Alternatively, why not have a data structure which allows you to store a URL *or* a local file, and simply know which is which rather than putting it all into a string representation?

Comment: Jon Skeet using the StartsWith and Substring is working. But could you please show me according to my code how to use the data structure ? Or give me an example of how to make and use data structure ?

Comment: @user1741587: Well, it's hard to know exactly what it would look like without knowing more about your app. But it could be a `LoadableResource` interface with separate concrete implementations for files and URLs, for example. Or you could just try to find a file-based URI which *would* work (I don't know what you're using to fetch data, or how it handles file URIs). Fundamentally though, using HTTP is misrepresenting the information you've got.

Answer (score 10):

> The problem is how can i remove the http:// ?

You may use [string.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx), and replace the string with an empty string.

```
targetDirectory = targetDirectory.Replace("http://","");
```

or

```
targetDirectory = targetDirectory.Replace("http://",string.Empty);
```

both of them are same

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if(example.StartsWith("http://"))
{
    example.substring(7); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) to remove / replace characters in the string.
Exampel:

```
targetDirectory = targetDirectory.Replace("http://", string.Empty);
```

And you can check if the string begins with Http:// by doing

```
if(targetDirectory.StartsWith("http://"))
```

Comment: Jon Skeet when its off line mode im using the same idea of recrusive function but this time from the hard disk. I put http:// since i have some functions in the program that check for dupe and duplicated links in the List. So i need to use http:// in the beginning. How else can i simulate the webcrawling ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the replace characters in the string by `string.Replace`

```
if (targetDirectory.Contains("http://"))
{
    targetDirectory = targetDirectory.Replace("http://",string.Empty);
}
```