# How to remove www, http/https and other strings in URL in C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing

For Example I have this string

```
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sample
```

What I want is to return only `merriam-webster.com` I'm planning to use `.Replace()` but I think there are better approach for this question.

Comment: You can see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062414/how-can-i-remove-the-part-http-from-a-string)

Comment: Where is this value came from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are working for Winforms then

```
string url = "http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sample";

UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder(url);

MessageBox.Show(ub.Host.Replace("www.",""));
```

and for web,

[Get host domain from URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14211973/get-host-domain-from-url)

Comment: what if the url is something like this `http://www.merriam-websterwww.com/dictionary/sample` ?

Answer (score 6):

How about this

```
System.Uri uri = new Uri("http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=something");
string uriHost = uri.Host;
```

?

Comment: Uri.Host still returns the www, but I think I will just use .Replace with that problem

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
        var a = "http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sample";
        var b = a.Split('.');
        var c = b[1] +"."+ b[2].Remove(3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Answers here don't handle the case like "http://abcwww.com". 
Check if the url starts with 'www.' before replacing it.

```
if (url.StartsWith("www.", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    url = url.Replace("www.", string.Empty);
```

Comment: can you explain how it will fail?

Comment: Ahh StackOverflow removed the http & www. from my original comment above. Was trying to say it fails for "http//www.merriam-websterwww.com/dictionary/sample". It returns merriam-webstercom. https://dotnetfiddle.net/DSAHnU.

Comment: I went for url = url.Remove(0,4);

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `System.Uri` class:

```
System.Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/search?q=something");
string uriWithoutScheme = uri.Host + uri.PathAndQuery + uri.Fragment;
```

Or you can use below:

```
UriBuilder ub = new UriBuilder("https://www.google.com/search?q=something");
currentValue = ub.Host.Replace("www.", "");
```